# Get word from character index in textView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitextview

On a tap of the UITextVIew, I am attempting to get the word where the tap occurred (using UITapGestureRecognizer placed in UITextView).  I am able to grab the index of the character selected, but I am not getting success grabbing the full word, it only seems works when I tap the first letter only.

```
func textTapped(_ tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let textView = textTapGestureRecognizer?.view as? UITextView {
        let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
        var location: CGPoint = textTapGestureRecognizer!.location(in: textView)
        location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
        location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top

        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        if characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length {

            // print the character index successfully
            print("character index: \(characterIndex)")

            // print the character at the index successfully
            let myRange = NSRange(location: characterIndex, length: 1)
            let substring = (textView.attributedText.string as NSString).substring(with: myRange)
            print("character at index: \(substring)")

            let tapPosition: UITextPosition? = textView.closestPosition(to: location)
            //fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
            if let textRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition!, with: .word, inDirection: 1) {
                if let tappedWord = textView.text(in: textRange) {
                    print("selected word :\(tappedWord)")
                    //This only prints when I seem to tap the first letter of word. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am always able to print out the character index and the character that was tapped, however, grabbing the word is the issue.  How can I grab the entire word from a textView with the character index everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue apparently seemed to stem from the .x and .y values I set after getting location.  All I had to do was remove these lines:

```
location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top
```

Comment: Oh good. That's a much better solution than the roll-your-own answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you could change your call to `rangeEnclosingPosition()` to granularity `.character`, then get an array of the word's characters and searches backwards for a word boundary, then forwards and build the range yourself.